# redux-form fields are resetting when changing a value attached to redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've configured a redux-form with three fields as follows:

```
function mapState(state) {
    return {
        initialValues: {
            terms: state.register.toJS().terms.value
        }
    };
};

[map dispatch object here]

export const MyFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm',
    fields: ['email', 'password', 'terms']
}, mapState, mapDispatch)(MyForm);
```

Each field spreads the passed props as per the docs e.g. {...email}.  The terms checkbox contains an onChange which calls an actionCreator to update my redux state:

```
<input type="checkbox" {...terms} onChange={this.handleTermsToggle.bind(this)}/>
```

When clicking the checkbox, the email and password fields are both reset to blank, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle. I needed to remove that chunk of the state tree altogether, and instead, use { change } from 'react-redux' in my outside component to modify the value.

```
import { change } from 'react-redux'

<button onClick={() => {
  this.props.change('myForm', 'terms' true);
}}>Click Me</button>

... and don't forget to map change to mapDispatchToProps
```